# figured out spatial user search, but how do i order it by distance? (php laravel mysql)

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, spatial

After a night of messing around, I managed to get a user search by distance going! something I've wanted to achieve for ages. However I have another problem. I cant sort them by distance.

I have a users table. Each user has a 'country', 'state', 'postcode' and 'suburb'.

i also have a places table with the following fields.

'country', 'state', 'postcode' and 'suburb', longitude, latitude

I managed to hack up a query which returned all the places in order by distance. But now I would like to return all users from that suburb, postcode, state and country, by order of distance.

this is the code I have so far and im not sure how to modify it.

```
//spatial queries

                static function cmp($user1, $user2)
                {
                    global $places;

                    foreach($places as $place)
                    {
                        if(($place->country == $user1->country) && ($place->suburb == $user1->suburb) && ($place->state == $user1->state))
                        {
                             return true;
                        } 
                        if(($place->country == $user2->country) && ($place->suburb == $user2->suburb) && ($place->state == $user2->state))
                        {
                             return false;
                        } 
                    }
                    return false;
                }

public function search()
{
    if (Auth::guest()) 
    {
        return Redirect::guest('/');
    }
    else
    {
        if ( Session::token() !== request( '_token' ) ) {
            return Response::json( array(
                'searcherror' => 'Invalid Authorization Token'
            ) );
        }





        //identify the right query (make sure later: if you arent what they are looking for, they dont show up. If you are blocked, they dont show up)


        if(request('country') && request('lfmin') && request('lfmax'))
        {

            //main requirements exist
            if(!request('state') && !request('suburb') && !request('postcode') && request('distance'))
            {   





                //spatial queries

                //$circle_radius = 3959; //miles
                $circle_radius = 6371; //kms
                $max_distance = request('distance');
                $lat = Auth::user()->getLoc()->latitude;
                $lng = Auth::user()->getLoc()->longitude;

                //get all nearby places
                 $places = DB::select(
                               'SELECT * FROM
                                    (SELECT id, country, suburb, state, latitude, longitude, (' . $circle_radius . ' * acos(cos(radians(' . $lat . ')) * cos(radians(latitude)) *
                                    cos(radians(longitude) - radians(' . $lng . ')) +
                                    sin(radians(' . $lat . ')) * sin(radians(latitude))))
                                    AS distance
                                    FROM places) AS distances
                                WHERE distance < ' . $max_distance . '
                                ORDER BY distance;
                            ');


                 /*

                $result = User::contains('country', $places->country)
                ->contains('state', $places->state)
                ->contains('postcode', $places->postcode)
                ->contains('suburb', $places->suburb)
                ->get();
                */

                $countryarray = [];
                $suburbarray = [];
                $statearray = [];

                foreach($places as $place)
                {
                    //get country array
                    //get state array
                    //get suburb array
                    array_push($countryarray, $place->country);
                    array_push($suburbarray, $place->suburb);
                    array_push($statearray, $place->state);
                }

                $places = (object)$places;


                $users = User::whereIn('suburb', $suburbarray)
                ->whereIn('country', $countryarray)
                ->whereIn('state', $statearray)->get();

                //put this somewhere useful later remember usort(array,'cmp')

                $users = $users->toArray(); // Convert user collection to array

                 //static


                usort($users, array("App\Http\Controllers\SearchController", "cmp"));





                return Response::json( array(
                            'searcherror' => $users
                        ) );  
            }
```

EDIT: tried that, fixed classpath got this

Invalid argument supplied for foreach()

theres something wrong with your sort function

Notes: user location along with longitude and latitude can be accessed by method in user object

$user->getLoc()
so basically we can access it like this for example
$user->getLoc()->longitude

Answer (score 1):

You can now sort the user array using a custom comparator which will use the sorted places array to compare between two user.

Code example -

```
class SomeController
{
    function someFunction()
    {
        $places = ...; // The places are already calculated by you
        $users = ...; // Users are also fetched in the code

        $users = $users->toArray(); // Convert user collection to array

        usort($users, function($user1, $user2) use($places)
        {
            foreach($places->toArray() as $place)
            {
                if(($place->country == $user1->country) && ($place->suburb == $user1->suburb) && ($place->state == $user1->state))
                {
                     return true;
                } 
                if(($place->country == $user2->country) && ($place->suburb == $user2->suburb) && ($place->state == $user2->state))
                {
                     return false;
                } 
            }
            return false;
        });

        // The array $users is now sorted based on user places
    }
}
```

You can also optimize the search of places using a hashmap kind of structure which will speed up your code complexity.

Comment: thanks for your assistance man, its GREATLY appreciated.

I tried however I ran into this:

usort() expects parameter 1 to be array, object given

Comment: Okay, The ->get() method returns a Collection Object which we need to convert to array before using in usort. I have updated the code accordingly . Have a look

Comment: I have incorporated toArray() into the $users object.
No dice. please see my edit

Comment: Referring to the php usort documentation https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.usort.php#refsect1-function.usort-parameters , If you are using it in a class then your comparator needs to be a static method, and you need to pass array of className and the comparator

Comment: not sure exactly what you mean. wont let me make the function static and dont know where to put it

Comment: I am assuming you are doing all these calculations in a laravel Controller class. Generally a class has many methods, you need to add your comparator as one of the methods too and that will be a static method.

Comment: yes i am doing it in a controller. all this is in the same controller method exactly as is. 

Could you please see my new edit?

Comment: Please move the method "cmp" out from the same method. and write that method as static function cmp() . Please see my code sample for better understanding

Comment: thank you for your patience. i tried that and ran into another problem.
please see my edit

Comment: ok sorted it by doing this

usort($users, array("App\Http\Controllers\SearchController", "cmp"));

and i get this error

Invalid argument supplied for foreach()

there is something wrong with your function

Comment: $places is not accessible in the scope. I have edited for an alternate solution, have a look

Comment: posted a final solution. figured out how to edit the sql query!

Answer (score 1):

here is my final solution! got it!
just had to modify the sql query and add a left join :D

waaaa hoooo !!!!!

```
//spatial queries

                //$circle_radius = 3959; //miles
                $circle_radius = 6371; //kms
                $max_distance = request('distance');
                $lat = Auth::user()->getLoc()->latitude;
                $lng = Auth::user()->getLoc()->longitude;

                //get all nearby places
                 $places = DB::select(
                               'SELECT * FROM
                                    (SELECT users.id, users.country, users.suburb, users.state, places.latitude, places.longitude, (' . $circle_radius . ' * acos(cos(radians(' . $lat . ')) * cos(radians(latitude)) *
                                    cos(radians(longitude) - radians(' . $lng . ')) +
                                    sin(radians(' . $lat . ')) * sin(radians(latitude))))
                                    AS distance
                                    FROM users
                                    LEFT JOIN places ON users.suburb=places.suburb) AS distances
                                WHERE distance < ' . $max_distance . '
                                ORDER BY distance;
                            ');


                 /*

                $result = User::contains('country', $places->country)
                ->contains('state', $places->state)
                ->contains('postcode', $places->postcode)
                ->contains('suburb', $places->suburb)
                ->get();
                */



                $places = (object)$places;


                return Response::json( array(
                            'searcherror' => $places
                        ) );
```